# Able to create a new record despite one to one entity relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using a Spring Boot H2 memory database and have three tables :

Loan,
Album,
Customer

The `loan` and `customer` are joined on a `one-to-one` while the `loan` and `album` tables are joined on a `many-to-many`

A `customer` can only create one `loan` and a `loan` can only have one `customer`. Yet I am able to create a new loan with the same customer and a new album list.

**Here is my loan Entity :**

```
@Entity
public class Loan implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x62B6DA99AA12AAA8L;

@Column @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private    Integer id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "loan_album", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "loan_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Customer customer;

// @Column private Integer customerId;
@Column private Date dateLoaned;
@Column private Date dateToReturn;
@Column private Boolean expired;

public Loan() {

}

public Loan(Customer customer, Date dateLoaned, Date dateToReturn,List<Album> albums) {
    this.albums = albums;
    this.customer = customer;
    this.dateLoaned = dateLoaned;
    this.dateToReturn = dateToReturn;
    this.expired=false;
}
```

**And here is my Customer Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x63A6DA99AA12A8A8L;

@Column @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private Integer id;
@Column private String firstname;
@Column private String surname;
@Column private String address;
@Column private String town;
@Column private String postcode;
@Column (unique=true) private String personalnumber;
@Column (unique=true) private String emailaddress;
@Column private Boolean enabled;

@OneToOne()
private Loan loan;

public Customer() {

}

public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String address, String town, String postcode, String personalnumber, String emailaddress) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.address = address;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.town = town;
    this.personalnumber = personalnumber;
    this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    this.enabled=true;
}

public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String address, String postcode, String town, String personalnumber, String emailaddress, Loan loan) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.address = address;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.town = town;
    this.personalnumber = personalnumber;
    this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    this.enabled=true;
    this.loan = loan;
}
```

**Album Entity :**

```
@Entity
public class Album implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x63A6DA99AA12AAA8L;

@Column @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private Integer id;

@Column (unique=true) private String barcode;
@Column private String band;
@Column private String title;
@Column private String genre;
@Column private Integer year;
@Column private String artworkFilename;
@Column private Boolean enabled;
@Column private Boolean isLoanable;
@Column private Integer numberOfCopies;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "album")
private List<Loan> loan = new ArrayList<>();

public Album() {

}

public Album(String barcode, String band, String title, String genre, Integer year, Integer numberOfCopies) {
    this.barcode = barcode;
    this.band = band;
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.isLoanable = true;
    this.numberOfCopies = numberOfCopies;
}

public Album(String barcode, String band, String title, String genre, Integer year, Integer numberOfCopies, List<Loan> loan) {
    this.barcode = barcode;
    this.band = band;
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.isLoanable = true;
    this.numberOfCopies = numberOfCopies;
    this.loan = loan;
}
```

**Exception :**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-08 08:12:11.570 ERROR 11132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.library.demo.entity.Loan.album in com.library.demo.entity.Album.loan
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.library.demo.BootLibraryApplication.main(BootLibraryApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.library.demo.entity.Loan.album in com.library.demo.entity.Album.loan
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One to One:** 
here is for `OneToOne` mapping relationship in your customer Entity, set `nullable = true` to allow Customer to created without Loan:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
mappedBy = "customer", nullable = true) 
private Loan loan;
```

and have Customer in your loan Entity..

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

**Many to Many: Have your relationship from Loan side like below to albums:**

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "loan_album", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "loan_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in Album entity mapped by Loan.

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "album")
private List<Loan> loan = new ArrayList<>();
```

Make sure you have spring data jpa dependency in your pom:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: As soon as I add these kind of annotations I get compilation errors.

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.library.demo.entity.Loan.album in com.library.demo.entity.Album.loans

In my Album class :    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "album")
    private List<Loan> loans;

Comment: please show me you pom, make sure you have spring data jpa dependency in it and also show me compile error.

Comment: I have added the pom as an answer. it's difficult to add follow up information with twitter style comments. I can't post another "answer" for 3 minutes with the error. I have the dependency.

Comment: you can update question with followed information..if possible then please push your code to github I can look at as I need to see all of your three entities..as I have created at my end and no issue..but let me also use your pom..if any issue at my end.

Comment: can you also check my updated answer for your Loan entity as Loan should be list in album as you want to many to many for it..in mean time checking your code.

Comment: I have a list there, yes. I have updated the original question with all the classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181454/discussion-between-kj007-and-reptile).